# RequestPermissionsAsync never returns

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the permissions plugin for Xamarin Forms . 
When i call  RequestPermissionsAsync  the call seems stuck forever . The next line is never called . 
I am doing the setup correct exactly as the documentation . 
That is my code

var result = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location, Permission.Camera, Permission.Microphone, Permission.Storage);

Console.WriteLine(result)   //this line is never called

Below is the manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.commonground.streetdeploy.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />

<application android:label="Street Deploy" android:allowBackup="false" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">

    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="com.commonground.streetdeploy.fileprovider" 
          android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
     <!--<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="xxx" />
         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxx" />
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="xxx" /> 
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="xxx" />--> 
</application>
```

This is the main Activity

[Activity(Label = "Street Deploy", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

```
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        /////////////////////////my code 





        await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();




        Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        UserDialogs.Init(this);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);



        /////////////////////////end my code 

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

```
      LoadApplication(new App());


    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have add user permission in specific platforms .

> in iOS (info.plist)

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>App want to access your Music </string>    
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>App want to access your Camera</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>App want to access your Microphone</string>  
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>App want to access your PhotoLibrary</string>
```

> in Android (Manifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And the line

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

will been called when you agree or reject the apply .

Comment: all that is already in place , i am asking because i spent hours trying to figure out what is the problem .

Comment: no did not , every thing is correct but it does not work . The call never returns .

Comment: it used to work fine in Vs 2017 , now in  2019  it does not ,  even with older emulators  .  I am using Xamarin Forms 4.0

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj in your project .Then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: It works fine on my project(in VS 2019). So can you share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test on my side .

Comment: Can i add you to my Git repo as a contributor so you can take a look ?

Comment: You can share a sample which contains your issue . You could not add my to your git . Because it will contain your personal information.

Comment: there is no personal information , it is ok  .  May i add you  ?

Comment: We couldn't do this because of Microsoft safety policy . You can share  a sample on git and post the path here .

Comment: i made a public repo here https://github.com/mtarshouby/publicstreetdeploy

Comment: the first time you run you will see how the call hangs

Comment: You should request the permission in Forms , not Android project .

Comment: var result = await PermissionsService.CheckPermissions( );  
in SplashPage.xaml.cs

Comment: did you see how the problem occurs ?

Comment: You can download the sample from https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/tree/master/samples and test it on your side . Though your project works fine in VS2017 . I think your code has no issue .

Comment: I cannot get it to work on a real device or the  Emulator . I am using VS 2019 now .

Comment: This sample works fine on  other user's side .So , you can reinstall your IDE .